# How to get current values of redux-form before submitting

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using redux-form library.
When I'm just filling the form, in redux-store I can see that new field is created:
"form" field, including all key-value pairs.
If I change any value, the key-value pair changes too.

How can I get all key-value pairs from this "form" field?

Comment: Always the `key` remains same as the field component `name`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `getFormValues` selector. Take a look at the [documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/selectors.md/) to see the usage.

```
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

...

const formValues = useSelector(state => getFormValues('my_form')(state))
```